# Is there a Pythonic way of handling this sort of range mapping

Tags: python

Can this be made more Pythonic please?

```
if joyx > 50:
   joyx = 100
elif joyx < -50:
   joyx = -100
else:
   joyx = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it using [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign) and [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=abs#abs) functions:

```
In [30]: from math import copysign

In [31]: joyx = copysign(100, joyx) if abs(joyx) > 50 else 0
```

Example:

```
In [32]: joyx = lambda x: copysign(100, x) if abs(x) > 50 else 0

In [33]: joyx(51), joyx(-51), joyx(50), joyx(-50), joyx(0)
Out[33]: (100.0, -100.0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I think this is a more elegant way of doing it but the original is clear enough.

Comment: Nice :)  I already have math loaded (its a 2000 line prog!)  Didn't know about copysign - that'll be very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what you have is perfectly Pythonic.

Because you are using less-than and greater-than comparisons, we can't really improve this by using a dictionary or any other trick I can think of.

I guess you could factor this out into a function and just call the function:

```
def clean_up_joystick(x, y, xbound, ybound, on_value):
    if x > xbound:
        x = on_value
    elif x < -xbound:
        x = -on_value
    else:
        x = 0
    if y > ybound:
        y = on_value
    elif y < -ybound:
        y = -on_value
    else:
        y = 0
    return (x, y)
```

For an actual program, I suggest you should make a class that manages the joystick, and init the class with the bounds values you want to use with any particular joystick.

Maybe something like this:

```
class Joystick(object):
    def __init__(self,
            x_low=-50, x_high=50,
            y_low=-50, y_high=50,
            on_value=100):
        self.x_low = x_low
        self.x_high = x_high
        self.y_low = y_low
        self.y_high = y_high
        self.on_value = on_value

    def read(self):
        # do something here that reads the joystick value
        # joystick value saved in x, y variables
        x, y = 0,0  # dummy init for example

        if x > self.x_high:
            x = self.on_value
        elif x < -self.x_low:
            x = -self.on_value
        else:
            x = 0
        if y > self.x_high:
            y = self.on_value
        elif y < self.x_low:
            y = -self.on_value
        else:
            y = 0
        return (x, y)

j = Joystick()
x, y = j.read()
```

Then in your actual program, you just use `j.read()` to read the joystick and clean up the input data.  If you need to change how it works, you have one place (the class).  Just make sure to have a different class instance for each actual joystick so you can clean up different joysticks if you have different ones.

Comment: :)  I think you know what I meant :) e.g. use an Python feature to make it shorter/sophisitcated.  As you say - the old way I learnt in BBC Basic is still not a bad way of doings things :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you find this more pythonic:

```
def get(joyx):
   joyx_min = -200
   joyx_max = 200
   from collections import namedtuple
   wheel_section = namedtuple("wheel_section", "min, max, output_value")
   roulette_wheel = [ wheel_section(joyx_min, -50, -100),  wheel_section(-50,51,0), wheel_section(51, joyx_max,100) ]
   for section in roulette_wheel:
     if  section.min <= joyx <  section.max:
       return section.output_value
   return 255
```

your code is a very simplified version of the roulette wheel algorithm.
I'm not sure you should really do a full scale version of it though.

### Update

A significantly shorter and prettier version that uses a lower bound algorithm:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

# an intentionally larger: maps also 50 and -50 for demonstrational purposes.
data = { -200 : -100, -100 : -50, -50 : 0, 50 : 50, 220 : 100 }
keys = list(data.keys())


print data[  keys[ bisect_left(keys, -79)  ]  ] # prints -100
print data[  keys[ bisect_left(keys,  15)  ]  ] # prints 0
print data[  keys[ bisect_left(keys,  67)  ]  ] # prints 50
print data[  keys[ bisect_left(keys,  250) ]  ] # prints 100
```

Comment: Like it but really looking for the one liner (if it existed) - ta :)

Comment: @SimpleSi This is an adaptation of the roulette wheel from genetic algorithms. Such things are mainly written in Java/C++. this is mainly usefull if you have more values than 3 (i.e. if you want to convert a float range into 10 distinct integer values). you could also perform binary search (smallest value larger than threshold) and map the found index to a set of discrete values. I could fit this into a (rather unreadable) lambda.